# How to create text file in outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I want to create a text file in outsystems. I have data in an entity and I want to create a text file using that entity's attribute values.

Can anyone provide an example showing how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TextToBinaryData` function and use its result in the `Download` node as *file content*, with the *Mime-type* set to `"text/plain"`.

The `TextToBinaryData` is available in the `Binary` extension which you probably have already installed in your environment, but perhaps you need to use *add/remove references* to make it available in your module.

You can use the `Download` node in any screen action as a terminal node (like the `End` node).

*References: [Download Files](http://www.outsystems.com/help/servicestudio/9.0/Designing_Actions/Download_Files.htm), [Binary Data API](http://www.outsystems.com/help/ServiceStudio/9.0/APIs/BinaryData_API.htm#TextToBinaryData)*

Comment: Its exactly what I want

Comment: Sorry sir I interacting with stack overflow from last 2 to 3 weeks. Now I know that answer is relevant then I have to mark the answer as accepted..