# How to assign structure to file content in download widget

Tags: outsystems

I have created structure list of entity records using `ListAppend`.

I have all the data in structure list i.e. around 11 records.

At movement I am getting only `[0]th` record of structure list because of assigned `File Content` in the    download  widget in that fashion (I showed in image below).
 I want to export that all 11 records into text file but I stuck to assign `File content` property of `Download Widget`

Detailed Description:

1. `StructureFNMA2Record` is my local variable for `ListAppend` Action
2. `StructureFNMA2RecordList` is my another local variable for `ListAppend` Action
3. So how I can assign that structure list of `ListAppend` to File Content that I will get all the 11 records in text file with new line after each index value of structure list

please help me..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier if you create a `Text` variable and write there what you want the file content to be. In that case you'll have a lot of freedom to manipulate the text as you wish and you can convert it to binary format and write it to the file when you're done.

The main idea is:

- Create a variable... let's call it `fileContent` and set its type to `Text`
- In the `ForEach` loop, instead of `ListAppend` use an `Assign` node
- In the assign node, set `fileContent` as the variable
- For the value, use something like `fileContent + StructureFNMA2RecordList.Current.Name + [...rest of your fields...] + NewLine()` ⇒ you're essentially appending content to the fileContent variable
- Outside the loop, use your Download node just with `TextToBinaryData(fileContent)` because by now the variable contains everything you'll want to write in the file

This should give you a file with the fields in each line. You'll probably want to put something between the fields because concatenating `Name` and `Phonenumber` will give you `Bankat12345` but if you put a space `" "` or something else in between you'll have a more readable `Bankat 12345`.

Comment: Yes instead of ListAppend I used Assign node and followed further process that you discussed above and its working correct..

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over your record list using a foreach element, and assign each position record's value to a new text variable concatenating it with NewLine().

In the end, you should output this newly created variable to your text file, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698744/how-to-create-text-file-in-outsystems).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Its helpful Filipe Martins